# Perl can't find Multicast.pm

Tags: perl, mod-perl

```
[root@newserver Socket]# /root/scripts/filetest testfile.txt
Can't locate loadable object for module IO::Socket::Multicast in @INC (@INC
contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Socket /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
```

filetest is calling "use IO::Socket::Multicast;"

The contents of the directory `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Socket` is the following:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 12342 Mar 22  2017 INET.pm  
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 14201 Nov 30 10:13 Multicast.pm  
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  3111 Mar 22  2017 UNIX.pm
```

Why can't perl find the Multicast.pm?

Comment: did you install the multicast module first?are these two different modules? could there be another location for the modules?

Comment: It looks like you've mixed up a locally built copy of perl with the system perl? What is going on with this system?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the path to Multicast.pm was a symbolic link and it appears that Perl didn't like it. Once I removed the symlink and just copied the files I needed over it was fine.

Comment: There is no sign of a symlink in your directory listing in the question. Are you sure?

Comment: If you're certain this actually worked, you can accept your own answer to resolve this post.